# 'PlaySounds.audio' hides inherited member 'Component.audio'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, playsound

I have seen a similar error to this but for Video, however I can not find anywhere that explains my current error.

I will attach my code below for reference, does anyone know what the error means here?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlaySounds : MonoBehaviour {

public AudioClip SoundToPlay;
public float Volume;
AudioSource audio;
public bool alreadyPlayed = false;
void Start()
{
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (!alreadyPlayed)
    {
        audio.PlayOneShot(SoundToPlay, Volume);
        alreadyPlayed = true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The MonoBehaviour class is already presenting a member called "audio" so your PlaySounds class has that member already. If you want to ignore the one from the base class you should declare it like so:

```
private new AudioSource audio;
```

But if you want the inherited member to be available as well as the one in your class simply give it a name other than "audio". To be honest unless you have a particular reason you want to override the inherited member I'd do the latter.